# jQuery tmpl() for MooTools?

Tags: javascript, mootools, jquery-templates

Is there a library for [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) analogous to [jQuery-tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/) [library](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MooTools Template Engine](http://mootools.net/forge/p/moo_template_engine) is the closest you'll probably come.

**Update**: Scratch that, [MooTools Forge](http://mootools.net/forge/p/mooml) looks promising.

Comment: Not precisely the same, but great candidates nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: Reading through it, MooTools Forge looks to be even more powerful than jQuery-tmpl. Even the template mark-up is straight js (Debugging complex jQuery templates becomes a bit of a pain). If I were to pick between the two, I'd go with it.

Comment: jQuery templates have worked best for me when they are slim, and call other templates for complex objects. Once I learned not to fool with too much if/then/loops I got to really like them. I'll have to kick the tires on these to see if they meet my needs. Thanks again!